# After Cloning my 80gb hdd to a 1tb hdd, ubunutu reads it as the 80gb.

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, clone

The 80gb is not in the computer. How do I make it read and use the full tb?

Answer (score 0):

The image you wrote to the new HDD is of an 80 GB partition so the computer sees only an 80 GB partition. You should use something like [GParted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/) to resize the 80 GB partition to use the whole 1 TB drive, or whatever portion you want to use that is.

Comment: Your answer would be improved if you would explain how as in this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions

Comment: I was expecting this to get closed as a duplicate pretty quickly so I kept the answer short.

Comment: Understood. Good habits make for better answers though. You can always post a comment regarding a possible duplicate to help others find it as well. Seems a better strategy than wasting time on a short answer. Just a thought. ;-)